# Simple (?) RewriteRule for htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this permalink:

http://MY-SITE/dett.php?piva=02181130041&id=58&pv=NO

All the informations after '?' are about the customer.
What I did for SEO request, was changing the link to that:

http://MY-SITE/CUSTOMER-NAME/dett.php?piva=02181130041&id=58&pv=NO

To make these new permalinks work, I need to edit the .htaccess with a RewriteRule, is it correct?
Can anyone help me to write this rule correctly?

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
#RewriteRule 
^\/([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\/dett.php?piva=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&id=([0-9]+)&pv=([a-zA-Z]+)$ dett.php?piva=$2&id=$3&pv=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: A.) - I feel like putting the customers name out there like that is an invasion of privacy, B.) post the code you currently have.

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for your replay. Customer was not the right word, they're part of a network of sellers, so there is no problem on showing them. This is what they want.

Comment: I was trying to do something like that `#RewriteRule ^\/([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\/dett.php?piva=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&id=([0-9]+)&pv=([a-zA-Z]+)$ dett.php?piva=$2&id=$3&pv=$4 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 2):

All you seem to be doing is knocking out the first URI and carrying over everthing else as is. I think this fits what you're asking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w\.-]+)/dett.php$ dett.php [L]
```

But I can't say I understand. Seems like there's gotta be more to the requirement.

You want the client to request this:
`http://MY-SITE/CUSTOMER-NAME/dett.php?piva=02181130041&id=58&pv=NO`

And you want to serve them this?
`http://MY-SITE/dett.php?piva=02181130041&id=58&pv=NO`

What's the point of `/CUSTOMER-NAME/` if you don't use it in the new URL somewhere?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! The real link is the second one without the name. What I want to do is change the permalink adding the name and make it works.
So, the link that I wanna show must stay on the right, correct?
Thanks again.

Comment: @ilGhera What do you mean **real link**? What do you mean **stay on the right**? A RewriteRule takes the form: `RewriteRule <pattern> <substitution>` where `<pattern>` is compared against all requests that come into to the server, and `<substitution>` is what you want to send back to the client when the `pattern` matches. Are you sure you need a RewriteRule? Can you give a real example for the request that will come into the server and what you want to serve back to the client?